# Suggestions on using NoSQL DB as FileStorage, and Pros & Cons

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

We are evaluating our options for alternatives to the static file storage (which is hosted among multiple geographic location).

- We are on Microsoft.NET platform (C#, ASP.NET, WEB API, SQL SERVER)
- We would like to store digital assets, mostly BINARY (AI, PSD, JPG, PNG, PDF, XLS, DOC...) files on any NoSQL DB.
- For image files it could contain thumbnail (small size) to original artwork (large file: ranges from 300 MB to more than 1 GB).
- Thumbnail would appear on the web page, but original would be available as an attachment with option to edit (User could download originals and edit using respective program and update the version).
- Each thumbnail and original needs to store multiple versions.
- We would not be hosting these digital asset on 3rd party platform (like Amazon S3, Azure) and CDN.
- This digital asset could be hosted on different geographic environment based upon user system configuration. (User in USA could store either USA, Europe, or ASIA based servers/db).
- Each storage needs to be replicated.

We are looking into MongoDB for this. Does anyone could suggest pros & cons based above assumptions or any other alternatives?

Some of MongoDB research reveals...

- Disk space consumption is 3 times larger than size of raw data
- Could cut down space consumption by -oplogSize parameter
- If We try to read chunk and stream to the browser speed could be 6 times slower than reading it from static file store.
- Replication is not bidirectional and it works as Master and Slave.

I have prototyped to read digital asset from static file system and store it to MongoDB GridFS in default chunk. What is the better approach in storing thumbnail and originals to MongoDB? As thumbnail would always be less than 16MB, but original could/not be more than 16MB, so by default should I store all image asset on GridFS?

I could envision to create different DB based upon content type, for example: one for PDF, Excel, Word, another for Image.

- How can we replicate among different servers?
- How can we store it among different MongoDB instance among different region?

I would really appreciate any input.

Thank you.

Comment: What are your requirements ACID-wise? Apart from NoSQL solutions, have you investigated the use of SQL Server 2008 (and newer) FILESTREAM?

Comment: why you wanna store file itself in a database? why not store the file on S3 and store the path to database? any particular reason? One of the problem with storing files in data is, it makes it difficult to manipulate , ie: resize, compress them on the fly.

Comment: @Lucero Thanks for your reply. We would be streaming thumbnail from MongoDB using HttpHandler or Web API to the web based application. So it should be available all the time. We do use SQL Server 2008R2, but have not evaluated for storing it as BLOB. How does it scale up where we do have thousands of images? Also, we would not be using same server as a database and digital asset, so we have to get several sql server licenses, which could add up the cost.

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks for your reply. All the database and file servers are needs to be hosted in client environment. That is why S3 is not an option.

Comment: @user1810385, it does scale pretty well, this seems like a very close fit to what FILESTREAM was designed for. All data is then stored in the file system and it scales as well as your file system does (typically NTFS, but SANs are also supported), which is pretty good with many files. It also supports SQL Server replication. Have a look at [this Whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh461480).

Comment: @Lucero Certainly. I would have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Some of MongoDB research reveals...
>
> Disk space consumption is 3 times larger than size of raw data Could
>   cut down space consumption by -oplogSize parameter If We try to read
>   chunk and stream to the browser speed could be 6 times slower than
>   reading it from static file store. Replication is not bidirectional
>   and it works as Master and Slave.

Did you tried to store data or just found some info somewhere? There is always an overhead if you are using a database (no matter which) than a plain filestorage. Why? Well, you have indexes and meta information.

mongodb is a shared nothing strong consistent db. So you write your data to one node and it then gets replicated. But you can use WriteConcerns (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#write-concern) to wait and so make sure that your data is been written to a number, majority etc of nodes in a replicaset. With replication you can do rolling upgrades without downtime and it is also very easy to scale using sharding. And using shard-tags to 'pin' documents to specific shards. see here: http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/